# Append html content to html file in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, cordova, android-activity

I want a way to update the html file after a function is called.

```
public class MainActivity extends /* Activity */DroidGap {

    private Object request;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MainActivity"); 
   super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }
   public void XXX(Dialog source, File file) {
                 source.hide();
                 String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

                String html_tag = "<input type = 'text' id='file_1' value='test' />";

                appView.loadData("javascript:appendText("+html_tag+")", "text/html", "utf-8");
  }         

}
```

This is a sample code but what happens is that I loose the entire data from index.html page.

How do I append additional html content to the existing html page.

I am developing this app using phonegap.

Additional info: `activity_main.xml` file code is pasted below:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.filepicker.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: editing html resources on android? you are doing it horribly wrong

Comment: @mvp: Do you have an answer to my question... If yes then do let me know

Comment: I don't. Note that on android assets do not necessarily correspond to actual files - they are stored compressed in APK. It is possible to extract them onto sdcard with some effort, but I don't think you've done that. That said, I would strongly suggest you rethinking your approach